# Warnings from last compilation - Unable to read text files/find directory

Tags: java

I need some guidance on why my code isn't working.

I have finished writing it however I keep getting a warning before I compile the code.

The warning is:

> "Warnings from last compilation... uses unchecked or unsafe operations. Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details".

When I compile the code the classes have compiled with no syntax error.

Only problem is that when I enter the file name it wasn't able to find the file, and I entered in the exact directory.
Code:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
/**
* The purpose of this class is to read data
 * (line-by-line) from a file.
 */
public class TextFileReader {
private static List list=new ArrayList(50);
private static List removeList=new ArrayList(50);
private static int min=999;
private static int max=0;
private static String minLine=null;
private static String maxLine=null;
/**
 * reads data from a given file line by line, processes
 * and then prints it out
 * @param fileName the name of the file to be processed
 * @return none
 */
public static void processFile(String fileName) throws IOException{
    System.out.println("file name: " + fileName);
    BufferedReader in
    = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName));//read text file
    String line;
    while ( (line = in.readLine()) != null) // reads every line
        getTokens(line);
    displayResult();
}

/**
 * split a given line into several token
 *
 * @param line the line to be split
 * @return none
 */
public static void getTokens(String line){
    StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(line, " ");
    int count = st.countTokens();//get total tokens in this line
    String firstToken=st.nextToken();
    String secondToken = " ";
    if(count >= 2)
        secondToken=st.nextToken();
    if(!Character.isDigit(firstToken.charAt(0)) && (count == 1 ||                 Character.isDigit(secondToken.charAt(0)))){
        list.add(line);
    }
    else{
        removeList.add(line);
    }
    // code to process and print out the result
}

public static void displayResult(){
    String minStr ="";
    String maxStr = "";
    int min = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    int max = 0;
    int scoreCount = 0;
    int sum = 0;
    for(int i=0; i<list.size(); i++){
        scoreCount = 0;
        StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(list.get(i).toString(), "    ");
        int count = st.countTokens();//get total tokens in this line
        String firstToken=st.nextToken();
        sum = 0;
        if(st.hasMoreTokens()){
            scoreCount++;
            sum = sum + Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken());
        }
        if(sum !=0)
            sum = sum/scoreCount;
        if(min > sum ){
            min = sum;
            minStr = list.get(i).toString();
        }
        if(max < sum){
            max = sum;
            maxStr = list.get(i).toString();
        }
    }
    System.out.println("MIN: "+minStr);
    System.out.println("MAX: "+maxStr);
    System.out.println("Excluded Entries:");
    for(int i=0; i<removeList.size(); i++){
        System.out.println(removeList.get(i).toString());
    }
}
// other methods ...
public static void main(String arg[]) throws IOException{
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter File name :");
    String fileName = scan.next();
    processFile(fileName);
}
}
```

Text file:

```
alex 10 20 30

2.4 10 20 george

bob 40 60

jane 10

100 jeff

Malcom

Jeff 10 20 30 40
```

Comment: Can you give the path of the file you are giving as input??

Comment: I gave some input on the "xlint" aspect; but to know about your real problem, you have to add the stack trace information to your question!

Answer (score 3):

That -Xlint thing is caused by this line:

```
private static List list=new ArrayList(50);
```

You are declaring a **[raw](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/rawTypes.html)** type here. Bad practice; don't do that. Ever. And it is easily fixed:

```
private static List<String> list = new ArrayList<>(50);
```

(assuming that your list is a List of Strings)

And for the record: you could have found that operation ... by running javac with that extra option. Important lesson here: **always** strive to achieve zero warnings/errors/whatever. Any information the compiler gives you is helpful; and you make sure to get rid of *any* warning.

Beyond that: I quickly ran you code; and **opening** the file works for me. But then the program fails with another exception. The reason for that:

```
String firstToken=st.nextToken(); // in your getTokens()
```

Thing is: you **first** have to check if there is a token! Point is: you have **empty** lines in your input file; and that for sure means that **not** each line will contain tokens. You have to add checks there; for example like:

```
if (line.trim().isEmpty()) {
// the line is empty and should not be processed
```